# ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments:[5213],[][][][], oracle 8

Tags: oracle, oraclereports, oracle8i

I have created this query to retrieve specific results. 
but, it gives me this error. 
I have records since 1995. so, if I want to retrieve all the data. I get the following error.

```
ERROR at line 38:
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments:[5213],[][][][]

SELECT TO_NUMBER(SOLF.I_NO) I_NO,
GEHA.G_NAME,
ITEMS.I_NAME,
TO_NUMBER(SOLF.G_NO) G_NO,
NVL(SOLF.SL_MONY,0) SL_MONY,
SOLF.SL_DATE THE_DATE,
SOLF.SRF_NO SRF_NO,
SOLF.SOLF_NO SOLF_NO,
SUM(NVL(TS_MONY,0)) TS_MONY,
NVL(SOLF.SL_MONY,0)- SUM(NVL(TS_MONY,0)) TOTAL, 1 THE_ORDER
FROM 
SOLF,TSDED,GEHA,ITEMS
WHERE
SOLF.SOLF_NO = TSDED.SOLF_NO(+)
AND GEHA.G_NO = SOLF.G_NO
AND
ITEMS.I_NO = SOLF.I_NO
GROUP BY SOLF.I_NO, 
GEHA.G_NAME,
ITEMS.I_NAME ,
SOLF.G_NO, 
SOLF.SL_MONY, 
SOLF.SL_DATE, 
SOLF.SRF_NO, 
SOLF.SOLF_NO
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TSDED.I_NO) I_NO,
GEHA.G_NAME,
ITEMS.I_NAME,
TO_NUMBER(TSDED.G_NO) G_NO,
0 SL_MONY,
TSDED.TS_DATE THE_DATE , 
TSDED.SRF_NO SRF_NO,
TSDED.SOLF_NO SOLF_NO,
SUM(NVL(TS_MONY,0)) TS_MONY,
0 -SUM(NVL(TS_MONY,0))  TOTAL, 2 THE_ORDER
FROM 
TSDED,GEHA,ITEMS
WHERE
GEHA.G_NO = TSDED.G_NO
AND
TSDED.SOLF_NO NOT IN 
(
SELECT SOLF_NO
FROM 
SOLF
)
AND
ITEMS.I_NO = TSDED.I_NO
GROUP BY TSDED.I_NO, 
GEHA.G_NAME,
ITEMS.I_NAME ,
TSDED.G_NO, 
TSDED.TS_DATE, 
TSDED.SRF_NO, 
TSDED.SOLF_NO
ORDER BY G_NO, I_NO , THE_ORDER ,THE_DATE ;
```

I have tried to fix it, but with no results. anyways, the error line is 38 which is : TSDED,GEHA,ITEM. 
my oracle database is 8i

Comment: The table is named items.  the error shows item... which is it?  http://www.dba-village.com/village/dvp_forum.OpenThread?ThreadIdA=4864 says to patch to 8.1.7 or increase  sort area size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Oracle are you running? If you are 
using a version below 8.1.6.3 you are probably 
hitting bug 1331849,

Description: Queries with a UNION ALL and more than 
one disk sort operation may fail with error ORA-600 
[[5213]]

http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/9968/

In general ora-00600 is an internal error, usually this is related to some internal structure getting corrupted or a bug in the database.

To work around the issue the easiest way I think is probably to use a table (temporary or not); separately insert the row you need there avoiding the union all and query the table.

Comment: oracle 8.1.6.0.0. I have read that post. didn't find any patch file

Comment: Yes the patch is distributed by Oracle Support. However, 8.1.6 has been out of support for so long (almost twenty years) it's the sort of thing Oracle only ship to highly favoured customers (i.e. companies which pay for super premium support). This is the risk of running ancient software without paying for a Support license.

Comment: The bug is with `union all`, what if `union` is used (to see if it works).

Answer (score 0):

If we assume each query in the union works w/o error; then 
Maybe forcing the engine to materialize the results then sort using an inline view/subquery.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT TO_NUMBER(SOLF.I_NO) I_NO
           , GEHA.G_NAME
           , ITEMS.I_NAME
           , TO_NUMBER(SOLF.G_NO) G_NO
           , NVL(SOLF.SL_MONY,0) SL_MONY
           , SOLF.SL_DATE THE_DATE
           , SOLF.SRF_NO SRF_NO
           , SOLF.SOLF_NO SOLF_NO
           , SUM(NVL(TS_MONY,0)) TS_MONY
           , NVL(SOLF.SL_MONY,0)- SUM(NVL(TS_MONY,0)) TOTAL
           , 1 THE_ORDER
FROM SOLF,TSDED,GEHA,ITEMS
WHERE SOLF.SOLF_NO = TSDED.SOLF_NO(+)
  AND GEHA.G_NO  = SOLF.G_NO
  AND ITEMS.I_NO = SOLF.I_NO
GROUP BY
  SOLF.I_NO,
  GEHA.G_NAME,
  ITEMS.I_NAME,
  SOLF.G_NO,
  SOLF.SL_MONY,
  SOLF.SL_DATE,
  SOLF.SRF_NO,
  SOLF.SOLF_NO
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TSDED.I_NO) I_NO
     ,  GEHA.G_NAME
     ,  ITEMS.I_NAME
     ,  TO_NUMBER(TSDED.G_NO) G_NO
     ,  0 SL_MONY
     ,  TSDED.TS_DATE THE_DATE
     ,  TSDED.SRF_NO SRF_NO
     ,  TSDED.SOLF_NO SOLF_NO
     ,  SUM(NVL(TS_MONY,0)) TS_MONY
     ,  0 -SUM(NVL(TS_MONY,0)) TOTAL
     ,  2 THE_ORDER
FROM TSDED,GEHA,ITEMS
WHERE GEHA.G_NO = TSDED.G_NO
  AND TSDED.SOLF_NO NOT IN (SELECT SOLF_NO FROM SOLF)
  AND ITEMS.I_NO = TSDED.I_NO
GROUP BY
  TSDED.I_NO,
  GEHA.G_NAME,
  ITEMS.I_NAME ,
  TSDED.G_NO,
  TSDED.TS_DATE,
  TSDED.SRF_NO,
  TSDED.SOLF_NO) mSub
ORDER BY
  G_NO,
  I_NO,
  THE_ORDER,
  THE_DATE;
```

Comment: Does each query run on its own?  Does it run w/o the order by?  Could you store the results in a temp table and then select from it so it's not going across disk (I'm looking at work arounds here.. the real answer is use a supported version)